# Word for supporting something that is harmful or not beneficial to you

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

If a person supports a group of people based on their own perception of that group. When in truth by supporting them they bring hardship on themselves whether it is physically, emotionally, or economically. Could even be supporting a political party that doesn't in truth cater to them.

Comment: The ultimate, very tragic example of this is [drinking the Kool-Aid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid). In metaphorical use, it doesn't necessarily imply that you bring hardship on yourself, but it does suggest that you're not being as critical as you ought to be.

Comment: @Morton That Kool-Aid is terrifying...

Answer (score 1):

### [Self-defeating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-defeating)

adj.
Injurious to one's or its own purposes or welfare.

Alternatively, you could say that supporting something that is not beneficial to you is [*counterproductive*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/counterproductive).

Answer (score 0):

Supporting something based on a false perception, and not in earnest would be *dissembling*.

> [Dissemble](http://gcide.gnu.org.ua/?q=dissemble&define=Define&strategy=.) (?), v. t. 
>   1. To hide under a false semblance or seeming; to feign (something) not to be what it really is; to put an untrue appearance upon; to disguise; to mask. [1913 Webster]

Answer (score 0):

If you are justly compensated for the trouble, it's called:

```
work
```

if you are not compensated:

```
volunteer
```

or if the members believes that their personal hardship is justified for the greater good then they are in:

```
a communion
```

Those are words with more or less neutral connotations.

If you're looking for a word with negative connotation, a group that tricks its flowers into following philosophies that are not beneficial to themselves is in a:

```
a cult
```